# How to add together (get the sum) a field from all author's posts

Tags: php, post-meta, count

Using the plugin [WPeddit](http://codecanyon.net/item/wpeddit-reddit-for-wordpress/4053648) I want to count the `epicredvote` score from all posts of an author together to get the sum.

The following is a custom field that puts out a score, like "3" or "-2" or whatever:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'epicredvote', true );
```

So I know, I have to build a loop somehow...

This is what I've found, but don't get a number on `$allscore`:

```
$authorPost = get_posts( array( 'author' => 1 ) );

foreach( $catPost as $post ); {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
}

$idList     = implode( ",", $ids );     //turn the array into a comma delimited list
$meta_key   = 'epicredvote';
$allscore   = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT sum(meta_value) 
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = %s 
        AND post_id in (" . $idList . ")
    ",
    $meta_key
) );

echo 'user 1 All posts View Count' . $allscore . ' ';
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing actually..I just don't know how to start...

Comment: you said it yourself, loop over the posts and do the add

Comment: Mark, thanks, but I'm just helpless.. I know the theory, but am still learning the practice :D I edited the question with the only thing I've found that is at least a bit in the right direction? Could you have a look?

Comment: Are you sure Author 1 has an epicredvote score? This is the first user created in the system and may / may not even exist or is likely to be an administrator. Also, you have a semi-colon at the end if your `foreach` statement which is not going to be valid.

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right with Author 1! To get the data of current displayed user I have to use `$current_user->ID` instead `'author' => 1` I think? . The semicolon was added by me, thought it has to be. If I delete the semicolon, Get this in the echo: _"Warning :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in "_.

Comment: Where are the votes stored? Does the plugin have any api, or at least some documentation?

Comment: Andrei, the only thing of documentation would be this: http://standalone.wpeddit.com/ The votes are stored inside the plugin in `$vote` I think. Also I found this: `'meta_key' => 'epicredvote',`

Comment: don't know if i can *bumb* this one :D

Answer (score -1):

First you have to declare the global $wpdb before using it. Also you need to include the table prefix when calling the table names.

```
global $wpdb;
$posts_table = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$posts_meta_table = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";
```

Next get an array of post ids by the author needed( make sure you have the id of desired author, assign to $author_id).

```
$authors_posts = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$posts_table." WHERE post_author = %d", $author_id) );
```

Make a comma delimited version of the post id array for SQL

```
$comma_delimited = implode(',', array_map('intval', $author_posts));
```

Next use the id array to make a sum of 'epicredvote' from the post meta table. Note the # of votes is stored in the meta_value column

```
$allscore = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT SUM(meta_value) 
    FROM " .$posts_meta_table . "
    WHERE (meta_key = 'epicredvote' 
           AND post_id IN %s)"
   , $comma_delimited));
```

Comment: Thanks Emily, but I get "_:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in_"